# Is there any way to align "=>" when printing out arrays?

Tags: php

When I use `<pre>` and `print_r()` on an array it looks something like this:

```
[Pacific/Midway] => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Midway
[Pacific/Niue] => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Niue
[Pacific/Tahiti] => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Tahiti
[Pacific/Marquesas] => (GMT-09:30) Pacific, Marquesas
[America/Adak] => (GMT-09:00) America, Adak
[America/Anchorage] => (GMT-08:00) America, Anchorage
[America/Juneau] => (GMT-08:00) America, Juneau
[America/Metlakatla] => (GMT-08:00) America, Metlakatla
```

It would be a *whole lot easier* to read if it looked like this:

```
[Pacific/Midway]     => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Midway
[Pacific/Niue]       => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Niue
[Pacific/Tahiti]     => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Tahiti
[Pacific/Marquesas]  => (GMT-09:30) Pacific, Marquesas
[America/Adak]       => (GMT-09:00) America, Adak
[America/Anchorage]  => (GMT-08:00) America, Anchorage
[America/Juneau]     => (GMT-08:00) America, Juneau
[America/Metlakatla] => (GMT-08:00) America, Metlakatla
```

Is there any way to do this when printing out arrays and objects (specifically arrays)?

Comment: no. var_dump/print_r are basic debugging output tools. they no "fancy" formatting capabilities. if you want something pretty, you'll have to roll your own code to do it.

Comment: This may be a start http://zavaboy.org/2011/11/09/php-improving-print_r-with-print_pre-wrapper-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick function to do that:

```
function format_array($a)
  {
  $k = array_keys($a);
  $v = array_values($a);
  $max_len = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<count($k); $i++)
      $max_len = max(strlen($k[$i]), $max_len);

  echo "<pre>";
  for ($i=0; $i<count($k); $i++)
    {
    echo str_pad($k[$i], $max_len)." => ".$v[$i]."\n";
    }

  echo "</pre>";
  }
```

Example usage:

```
$test = array("something" => 1, "something else" => 2,
        "and yet another one" => 3, "a" => 4);   
format_array($test);
```

Output:

```
something           => 1
something else      => 2
and yet another one => 3
a                   => 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is for debugging purposes. Install Xdebug, and use `var_dump()`. You get a lovely, pretty output.

It looks like this:

[image: Xdebug var_dump()]

This way, you don't have to clutter your own code with things to handle the output of data. It's just built into PHP.

I'd recommend installing Xdebug anyway, it's an incredible tool for many reasons.